# Were there ever oceans on Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, tatooine

Very little is told about the history of the planet Tatooine, but many facts indicate that the planet was not always desert (canyons, Dune Seas, sandy plains, salt flats). Weren't there oceans and/or thickets?

Even an [article on Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Great_Chott_salt_flat) gives some tips:

> Once the seabed of one of Tatooine's vast oceans, the salt flat became a dry expanse of a hard-packed fusion of clay and sodium-rich sand blown in from the Western Dune Sea.<sup>[[1]](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Great_Chott_salt_flat#cite_note-CL-0)</sup>

Comment: Geologic history is many,many times longer than the social and political history of intelligent beings.  There is unlikely to be any canon or noncanon Star Wars fiction set in the very distant past  eras when Tatooine had oceans.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Tatooine is pictured as having oceans in a brief scene in the comic series Dawn of the Jedi (now no longer considered canon).  If I can get a book for reference, I will respond as an answer.

Comment: @DragonChampion7 Yes, that's all true, but not yet shown in the new canon, although I always always believed that so as shown in the comic is a canon.

Comment: Besides, another fact is that many of the planets inhabitants draw water from the planets atmosphere via moisture farms using water vaporators.
Of course, according to the canon, the share of fresh water on Tatooine is about 1% of the entire planet. This may seem small, but at the same time the population of the planet is very small (about 200,000 people (including jawas and tuskens))
And if you compare it with the population of the Earth, and the amount of fresh water (2.5 - 3%), then this is quite enough and plausible.

Comment: Yes, there were. They appear in the pre-prequel movies by George Lucas. You can see it clearly in Star Wars: The Phantom Ocean. They evaporated when Greedo shot first.

Comment: This is a useless comment, but having been to Tatooine, Tunisia as part of my thesis: yes, very nearby is the Mediterranean :)

Comment: You don't have to go to comics or other no-longer-canon stuff for this.  In the original films (forget if it was Ep. IV or VI), there's a scene on Tatooine where the skeleton of a sea-serpent like creature is seen on the horizon.  If I could get a picture, I'd make an answer out of that.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - That's a [Krayt Dragon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Krayt_dragon) skeleton. They're land creatures...

Comment: I've always wondered what kind of farm his aunt and uncle had.  I didn't see a plant on the whole damn planet, and Luke's uncle was already talking about needing him for the harvest.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The fully canon book [*Ultimate Star Wars*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars) describes Tatooine as having once been possessed of life-bearing ocean(s) and a water cycle that included rain.

> According to Jawa folklore, the great Tatooine desert known as the
> Dune Sea was once a true ocean. **Ancient fossil-bearing rock and eroded
> canyons seem to confirm the Jawas' stories**, but most of Tatooine's
> inhabitants still find it hard to believe water ever flowed on the
> planet's arid, sand-covered surface.

The fact that the change occurred within the scope of 'folklore' would suggest that the shift was recent, geologically speaking, potentially within thousands (or at most tens of thousands) of years.

Comment: Since there is no longer much plant life, does that mean it will run out of oxygen at some point?

Comment: @z0r - I was intrigued to learn the other day that deep-core samples (on Earth) contained microbes at a depth of a mile or more and that these microbes may produce more oxygen than the entire surface biomass combined. Just because you can't see life doesn't mean that it's not out there in vast quantities.

Comment: @Valorum it's true that microbes exist that deep, and the "deep biosphere" might contain hundreds of times more biomass than the surface life we know. However, making oxygen requires photosynthesis, and there's no light underground. Those organisms are methanogens and other kinds of chemoautotroph - they don't make oxygen.

Answer (score 34):

The fact that Tatooine even has life and a breathable atmosphere would realistically mean that there was surface water at some point. Tatooine's inspiration from the *Dune* novels, Arrakis, had oceans at one point, but almost all the water ended up sequestered underground within the bodies of larval sandworms and underground reservoirs created by the sandworm burrowing.

In one comic, *Dawn of the Jedi*, it was described as "lush" with "gleaming cities set by blue seas":

> [image: Two yellow suns loom close over a world with white clouds, blue ocean, and green land.]
>
> Tatooine, a lush world where twin suns warm fair skies. A thriving world, where the Kumumgah live peacefully in gleaming cities along its blue seas.

Comment: This is a great answer (complete with a nice panel) but you might want to make it clear that this comic isn't part of Star Wars' official canon.

Comment: It may also be worth noting the Legends explanation for why Tatooine no longer has oceans by the time of the movies: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bombardment_of_Tatooine

Comment: So far as I know, there's no such thing as a canon Star Wars comic.

Comment: @david There have been many since the Disney reset. They are mostly published by Marvel.