# Does it rain on Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, tatooine

Tatooine is renowned as a 'desert planet' (although [not always so](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204158/were-there-ever-oceans-on-tatooine), it seems). The peoples of Tatooine seem to rely on high tech 'vaporators for their water, Jawas never bathe because they consider it wasteful of the water that they carefully hoard and recycle and the Sand People regularly attack settlements and sandcrawlers in order to get access to their water supplies.

**Does it ever rain on Tatooine?**

[image]

Answer (score 10):

**Yes, although we the audience don't actually see it happen.**

In the short story *[Master and Apprentice](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Master_and_Apprentice_(short_story))* (from the anthology [*From a Certain Point of View*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/From_a_Certain_Point_of_View)), Obi-Wan describes the desert thusly;

> Some believe the desert to be barren. This proves only that they do
> not know the desert.
>
> Deep within the dunes dwell small insects that weave nets to trap one
> another, and burrowing snakes with scales the color of stones so that
> no hunter can find them. **Seeds and spores from long-dead plants lie
> dormant in the warmth, waiting for the rainfall that comes once a
> year, or decade, or century, when they will burst into verdant life as
> brief as it is glorious.** The heat of the suns sinks into the grains of
> sand until they glow, containing all the energy and possibility to
> become glass the color of jewels. All of these sing individual notes
> in the one great song of the Whills.

---

Additionally, we see that there are dense clouds that form in the atmosphere. Cumulus clouds would generally imply periodic rainfall.

[image]

[image]

And we also learn from the [Complete Location](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Complete_Locations_(2016)) factbook that Tatooine does have *some* surface water, albeit scant. Again, this would generally imply replenishment.

> Surface Water: 1%
>
> ... Fossils bear testament to an ocean-covered formative period, although today Tatooine is **all but waterless.**

Comment: Aside from that,, the geology shown in the movies includes sandstone that presumably was cemented from originally loose sand, a process that required water at least in the deep past.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron - Tarooine was once much more watery; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204158/were-there-ever-oceans-on-tatooine